# Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot project, I try to get list of buckets. I don't have a bucket yet. Error is as follows:

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied
```

I created the access & secret keys an hour ago. I tried to delete and re-create bu no chance. Is there anything missing?

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
    "myaccesskey", 
    "mysecretkey"
    );

    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
    .build();

    try{
        List<Bucket> buckets = s3client.listBuckets();
        
        for(Bucket bucket : buckets) {
            response += bucket.getName();
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.print(exception);
    }
```

Comment: Does your IAM keys have proper s3 IAM policy or role attached, that has access to s3?

Comment: I added AmazonS3FullAccess to permission policies. I created a new key now it says: "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official guide to explicitly specifying credentials in Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html), you don't need to specify the region while instantiate the credentials.

Check also the permissions on the user for which you created the keypair, the ListBuckets API needs at least the **s3:ListAllMyBuckets** permission, as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding permission **AmazonS3FullAccess** on the **Permissions Policies** panel and restarted spring boot and all works well.